# Javascript to separate comma separated value within same column

Tags: javascript, csv

I have parse csv file into javascript object.

```
array[1] = ["2011-07-18", "373.800"]
array[2] = ["2011-07-19", "372.300"]
```

How can I make a new array that only consist?

```
["373.800", "372.300"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var items = [];
for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
    items.push( array[i][1] );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! very simple and clean!

Answer (score 0):

By creating a new array ?

```
<script>
    array = new Array();
    array[0] = ["2011-07-18", "373.800"];
    array[1] = ["2011-07-19", "372.300"];

    array2 = new Array();
    array2[0] = [array[0][1], array[1][1]];

    alert(array2[0]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer browser (I mean Chrome/Firefox 3+), you can achieve this easily by Array.map https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map. You could refer to Compatibility section to implement Array.map yourself for older browser compatibility.

```
if (!Array.prototype.map)
{
  Array.prototype.map = function(fun /*, thisp */)
  {
    "use strict";

    if (this === void 0 || this === null)
      throw new TypeError();

    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (typeof fun !== "function")
      throw new TypeError();

    var res = new Array(len);
    var thisp = arguments[1];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
      if (i in t)
        res[i] = fun.call(thisp, t[i], i, t);
    }

    return res;
  };
}

var array = [];
array[0] = ["2011-07-18", "373.800"];
array[1] = ["2011-07-19", "372.300"];
var result = array.map(function(ary) {
    return ary[1];
});
alert(result);
```